# Pattern Matcher Vs String Split, which should I use?

Tags: java, regex, string, performance, split

First time posting.

Firstly I know how to use both Pattern Matcher & String Split.
My questions is which is best for me to use in my example and why?
Or suggestions for better alternatives.

Task:
I need to extract an unknown NOUN between two known regexp in an unknown string.

My Solution:
get the Start and End of the noun (from Regexp 1&2) and substring to extract the noun.

```
String line = "unknownXoooXNOUNXccccccXunknown";
int goal = 12 ;
String regexp1 = "Xo+X";
String regexp2 = "Xc+X";
```

1. I need to locate the index position AFTER the first regex.
2. I need to locate the index position BEFORE the second regex.

A) I can use pattern matcher

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp1);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        int afterRegex1 = m.end();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        //TODO Exception Management;
    }
```

B) I can use String Split

```
    String[] split = line.split(regex1,2);
    if (split.length != 2) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        //TODO Exception Management;
    }
    int afterRegex1 = line.indexOf(split[1]);
```

Which Approach should I use and why?
I don't know which is more efficient on time and memory.
Both are near enough as readable to myself.

Comment: Why not just combine everything into a single regex, and then pull your noun out using a matching group?

Comment: `Matcher.groupCount();` does not count the number of occurrences! So this is not an alternative to `String.split()`.

Comment: @Holger is correct. You should either be using `Pattern.split()` or a loop counting how many times `m.find()` returns true.

Comment: Note that `UnsupportedOperationException` makes no sense here; this is a typical `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: @maaartinus Thanks I've made your change, that is the reason why I have `//TODO Exception Management;` I need to learn more about correct usage.

Comment: @willkil The counter would not be required but `Pattern.Split` is great.

Comment: edited to correct my mistakes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
String line = "unknownXoooXNOUNXccccccXunknown";
String regex = "Xo+X(.*?)Xc+X";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
   String noun = m.group(1);
}
```

The `(.*?)` is used to make the inner match on the NOUN *reluctant*.  This protects us from a case where our ending pattern appears again in the unknown portion of the string.

**EDIT**

This works because the `(.*?)` defines a *capture group*.  There's only one such group defined in the pattern, so it gets index 1 (the parameter to `m.group(1)`).  These groups are indexed from left to right starting at 1.  If the pattern were defined like this

```
String regex = "(Xo+X)(.*?)(Xc+X)";
```

Then there would be *three* capture groups, such that

```
m.group(1); // yields "XoooX"
m.group(2); // yields "NOUN"
m.group(3); // yields "XccccccX"
```

There *is* a group 0, but that matches the whole pattern, and it's equivalent to this

```
m.group(); // yields "XoooXNOUNXccccccX"
```

For more information about what you can do with the `Matcher`, including ways to get the start and end positions of your pattern within the source string, see the [Matcher JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Comment: In this example Wouldn't the noun also contain the unwanted boarding regexps?

Comment: No.  It won't.  The group is only the part in the parentheses.

Comment: WITCH CRAFT!
It works but I don't know why.
`regexp = "Xo+X(.*)Xc+X"` will match `XoooXNOUNXccccccX`in line.

how (or link me too) does it provide NOUN ?

Groupings of (0)(1)(2) in the Regexp, is this the answer to your sorcey. Can I select which part to return of the regexp with `m.group(1)` ?

Comment: Worth noting that this only correctly captures NOUN if there are NO other instances of Xc+X later in the string. If the string happened to be "unknownXoooXNOUNXccccccXunknownXcX" you'd capture "NOUNXccccccXunknown". I only mention this because the string is "unknown" - so it could happen. Updating your regex to "Xo+X(.*?)Xc+X" should fix this.

Comment: Good catch, @BunjiquoBianco.  I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @BunjiquoBianco I understand the problem I don't understand the solution. `(.*?)`

How does '?' = 0 or 1 times solve this?

In Natural Language how would that be written for me to understand? 

"NOUNXccccccXunknown" matched by `.*` 
and it found "NOUNXccccccXunknown" 1 time `?`. So for me the way I understand it theoretically I still have the incorrect answer.

Comment: @BunjiquoBianco had a think, does it work because it matches "NOUN" first and "NOUNXccccccXunknown" second. So to satisfy `?` is stops at the first match which is "Noun".

Comment: Adding the `?` after the `*` changes the meaning of the expression.  The `?` now means that the `*` quantifier is reluctant instead of greedy, which means that it will match the shortest possible string rather than the longest.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Comment: @AnotherCompilerError What Ian said! :D

Comment: OH GUYS!! You just saved my ass with the `(.?)` Quant thing.
I had a big problem occurring elsewhere in my code for a while and that completely saved me. I have no idea how I would of struggled to fix that otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `String.split()` for readability unless you're in a tight loop.

Per [`split()`'s javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), `split()` does the equivalent of `Pattern.compile()`, which you can optimize away if you're in a tight loop.

Comment: I was curious which performed better: Matcher or split, and this explains why Matcher (with a precompiled pattern) outperforms split.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to get a unique occurrence. For this do simply

```
input.replaceAll(".*Xo+X(.*)Xc+X.*", "$1")
```

For efficiency, use `Pattern.matcher(input).replaceAll` instead.

In case you input contains line breaks, use `Pattern.DOTALL` or the `s` modifier.

---

In case you want to use split, consider using Guava's `Splitter`. It behaves more sane and also accepts a `Pattern` which is good for speed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the locations you can do it like this:

```
String line = "unknownXoooXNOUNXccccccXunknown";
String regexp1 = "Xo+X";
String regexp2 = "Xc+X";

Matcher m=Pattern.compile(regexp1).matcher(line);
if(m.find())
{
  int start=m.end();
  if(m.usePattern(Pattern.compile(regexp2)).find())
  {
    final int end = m.start();
    System.out.println("from "+start+" to "+end+" is "+line.substring(start, end));
  }
}
```

But if you just need the word in between, I recommend the way Ian McLaird has shown.

Comment: This will work, but there's a (potential) problem with OP's approach in general terms.  What happens if `regexp2` occurs *before* `regexp1` in the source string (perhaps within the unknown text at the beginning)?  May not come up in practice, but the idea makes me slightly itchy.

Comment: @Ian McLaird: Since I re-use the `Matcher` it starts searching at the end of the previous match. It works as intended.

Comment: @Holger is is basically the version I had implemented but touch more elegant.

`m.usePattern` that is NICE much tidier than what I did.
I will retain that for the future.
However your correct I just need the word, not the locations.
I only used that to get to my goal.

Comment: @IanMcLaird with regards to the regexps 1&2 mismatch this shouldn't happened with my implementation due to the way I extract the string, this has been considered. thanks